# How to return numberOfRowsInSection?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I really need help as I am new to Swift. I am facing an issue where  I don't find a way to return **numberOfRowsInSection**

**Scenario:**

- I have 3 numberOfSections in tableview which I am returning from **sectionArray**, which is as follows:

  ```
  {
                      "mbsdcie6_2_1": "Incomer 132 KV Parameters",
                      "mbsdcie6_2_2": [
                          3,
                          6,
                          4,
                          5,
                          8,
                          30,
                          31,
                          7,
                          18,
                          29,
                          1
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "mbsdcie6_2_1": "SMS2 Parameters",
                      "mbsdcie6_2_2": [
                          9,
                          10,
                          11,
                          12,
                          13,
                          14
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      "mbsdcie6_2_1": "SMS 1 Parameters",
                      "mbsdcie6_2_2": [
                          15,
                          17
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
  ```

Using above array, I can return numberOfSections like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sectionArray.count
}
```

But, how to return **numberOfRowsInSection** using **sectionArray** ??

**Note:**

I want **numberOfRows** from **"mbsdcie6_2_2"** key of **sectionArray**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return "numberOfRows" // What to return here?
    }
    if section == 1 {
        return "numberOfRows"
    }
    if section == 2 {
        return "numberOfRows"
    }
    return 0
}
```

**Edit 1**

This is how I added data into sectionArray:

// It comes from another webservice, so I added it to userdefaults.

let headers = swiftyJSonVar["message"][0]["mbsdcie6"]["mbsdcie6_2"].arrayObject

```
kUserDefault.set(headers, forKey: kHeadersArray)
```

// In my another ViewController, I am retrieving it like this:

```
var sectionArray = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        sectionArray = kUserDefault.array(forKey: kHeadersArray) as! [Dictionary<String, Any>]

        print(sectionArray)
    }
```

I know it could be silly and It's way too easy but somehow I am stucked as I am new to it.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: just store all three array than pass count array value

Comment: please add code how you added array data in sectionarray

Comment: It seems that the `sectionArray` is actually a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if !sectionArray.isEmpty {
     let sectionContent = sectionArray[section]["mbsdcie6_2_2"] as? [Int]
    return sectionContent.count 
 } else {
     return 0
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if sectionArray.indices.contains(section),
        let sectionContent = sectionArray[section]["mbsdcie6_2_2"] as? [Int] {
        return sectionContent.count
     } else {
        return 0
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I didn't down vote. But I want numberOfRows for this key "mbsdcie6_2_2".

Comment: I did downvpote you. Your solution is simply wrong.

Comment: Check it out now... I didn't read the whole question.. @Desdenova

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let singleSection = self.sectionArray[section]
            if let rows = singleSection["mbsdcie6_2_2"] as? [Int] {
                      return rows.count
            } else {
                       return 0
            } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives a warning like this:  Conditional cast from '[String : Any]' to '[String : Any]' always succeeds. However, code works!